# How to align text by decimal point in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Say I have three numbers

2.55

2353.45

232.44

I want to write on canvas such that three numbers are aligned according to the decimal point as below.

```
     2.55

  2353.45

   232.44
```

I'm aware of context.textAlign property but it has only 5 options:left,right,center,start,end.
I have searched on the internet but I can't find any help.Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Please include a code snippet where it shows what you have which doesn't work, and also clarify what's the expected result. Help us reproduce the problem.

Comment: textAlign right should line then all up by decimal point (assuming all have same number of decimal digits)

Comment: Have a look at the edits

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`measureText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) method and its returned [TextMetrics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics) object in order to calculate the width of the digits prior to the dot.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  texts = [];
ctx.font = '14px sans-serif';
// fill our array with test-cases
for(var i=0; i<7; i++)
  texts.push(randLengthedNum() + '.' + randLengthedNum());

texts.forEach(drawText);

function drawText(str, i) {
  var left_part = str.split('.')[0],
    // get the width of the left part
    left_width = ctx.measureText(left_part).width,
    // the width of the dot
    dot_width = ctx.measureText('.').width,
    // places the '.' at center of the canvas
    x = (canvas.width / 2) - (left_width + (dot_width / 2));
  ctx.fillText(str, x, (i+1) * 20);
}

// return random lengthed numbers
function randLengthedNum(){
  return (Math.random()).toFixed(2+(Math.random()*8)|0).substr(2);
}
```

```css
#canvas{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```